# What is the difference between *&arr and *&arr[0] in C++, if arr is an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dereference

Suppose I have an array of integers called `arr`. I am trying to understand the distinction between `*&arr` and `*&arr[0]`.

I read that in C++, `arr` is essentially a pointer to the first element in the array and `&arr` is a pointer to the whole array. They both return the same address, I get this part. Then, if I enter `*&arr[0]` , then the first element, i.e. value at `arr[0]` is returned. But if I enter `*&arr`, then the address of `arr[0]` is returned. My question is, why when I use `*&arr`, is the address returned, rather than the first element? Logic would dictate that since the operator `*` returns value, one would expect `*&arr` to return the first element instead of an address.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you expect `*&arr` to return the first element? `*` and `&` cancel each other out, so `*&arr[0]` is equlivalent to `arr[0]`, and `*&arr` is equivalent to `arr`.

Comment: Maybe you should demonstrate what you are talking about with a [mre] (so we have a precise meaning for "if I enter", as we don't know where you are entering things)? Define `arr`, then output `*&arr[0]` and `*&arr`. While you're at it, also output `arr[0]` and `arr` and explain why you expect `*&arr[0]` to match `arr[0]` but do not expect `*&arr` to match `arr`.

Comment: The `*` operator gives an lvalue expression, which designates a memory location. It doesn't retrieve the stored value of that location (that operation is called lvalue-to-rvalue onversion)

Answer (score 3):

> I read that in C++, `arr` is essentially a pointer to the first element in the array

This is wrong. If `arr` is an array, then it is an array. Arrays are not pointers <sup>1</sup>.

> why when I use *&arr, is the address returned

Given that `&arr[0]` is a pointer to the first element, indirecting through the pointer (`*&arr[0]`) gives you an lvalue reference to the first element.

Given that `&arr` is a pointer to the array, indirecting through the pointer (`*&arr`) gives you an lvalue reference to the array. Just like `arr`, this array lvalue decays to a pointer to first element when converted to an rvalue.

Except for cases where the operators are overloaded, `*&` essentially cancel each other out. They are inverse operations. `*&arr[0]` gives you the same as `arr[0]` and `*&arr` gives you the same as `arr`.

---

<sup>1</sup> Except in declaration of function parameters, where an array parameter actually does not declare an array at all, but instead declares a pointer to element of such array.

Comment: • nit: declaration of a function and its _parameters_.  Arguments are what the callsite passes into functions.

Comment: @Eljay I was never able to learn which is which :) Especially confusing since they are also sometimes referred to as "formal" argument/parameter and "actual" argument/parameter in which context they are synonyms.

Comment: I finally used the mnemonic "arguments are like automobiles, and parameters are like parking spots".

Answer (score 3):

> I read that in C++, `arr` is essentially a pointer to the first element in the array

Then whatever you read is wrong.  It is true that arrays will decay into a pointer to their first element if you look at them wrong, but **arrays are not pointers**.

---

That out of the way:

- `*&arr` yields the whole array.  `&arr` forms a pointer to the array, and `*` dereferences that pointer.  Thus, the type of that expression is the same as `arr`.  Once again, this will decay into a pointer to the array's first element if you look at it wrong.  For instance if you try to print that with `std::cout << *&arr`, the array will decay to a pointer to its first element and probably end up calling the `operator<<(std::ostream&, void*)` overload.
- `*&arr[0]` yields the first element of the array.  `arr[0]` indexes into the array, `&` forms a pointer to the array's first element, then `*` dereferences that pointer.  The type of that expression is the same as `arr[0]`.

Answer (score 2):

One is an `int` expression, the other is an `int [N]` expression, for some size `N`.

> I read that in C++, `arr` is essentially a pointer

Throw that book away. It is dangerously imprecise. `arr` can convert to a pointer at a moment's notice, but it is most definately not a pointer.

> They both return the same address

But not the same type.

> My question is, why when I use `*&arr`, is the address returned, rather than the first element?

Because you have dereferenced a pointer-to-array. If you use `*&arr` in a context that expects a pointer, it decays to one, like any other array expression.